# Storyboarding for iOS and iPad

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ipad

I'm developing a simple app for the iPhone and was preparing to submit it for review from Apple.

I found out I needed to supply screenshots for the iPad and when I ran the simulator on the iPad nothing seems to display.

It looks like it's because my storyboarding height and width modes were set to Width: Compact, Height: Any.

First of all, to get it to render for iPad, do I need to re-storyboard for Height: Any, Width: Any.  Or do I have to do Height: Regular, Width: Regular?

Also will setting those mess up my current constraints and layout?

Finally do I have to use all new UILabels, Views, etc?  I'd like to use the old ones without messing up the positioning and constraints I've set, but I can't see anything when I change to Width/Height: Any.

Comment: Is your app iPhone only or universal?

Comment: Is it possible to make it iPhone only?  I was under the impression it had to be Universal.  I would prefer it was iPhone only

Comment: You can make an app iPhone only, in which case you don't need to upload iPad specific screenshots, but even iPhone only apps must run on an iPad at iPhone 4 resolution; so if your app simply produces a blank screen on an iPad your app will fail review.  Generally it is best to use "Any,Any" and then add specific size-class variations where required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your app is just an iPhone app, you don't need to submit iPad screenshots, you can submit with just the iPhone screenshots.

If you wish to make your app universal, you will have to ensure the storyboard is changed to support regular width/height as well. Also take into consideration multi-tasking support if the app is not marked for `full screen` specifically.

Answer (score 0):

If you are planning to make it support for iPad as well(Universal), Then probably you have to redo all the constraints you have considering the size classes you used at the moment. For iPad `wRegular` and `hRegular` recommended. Changing your size classes from `wCompact`, `hAny` to `wRegular`, `hRegular` will definitely mess up your existing constraints.

If your app is iPhone only, then you don't have to upload iPad screenshots at all.